# Named range in Excel/VSTO being returned even after it's been 'deleted' in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, named-ranges

I'm using VSTO (on Visual Studio 2008 due to a client request) to create Named ranges on single cells, which are then saved to the workbook and subsequently read when the application restarts.

If I delete a row containing one or more named ranges in excel, save my workbook and restart excel, the named ranges in said row are still returned, and this is causing my problem.

In order to name the cells, I am does a simple Application.Selection.Name = "whatever". And to get them back upon starup I am using Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names.

Can somebody please tell me if this is correct behaviour, and if so if there is any way to filter ranges - via the C# excel interop code - to only ones that are currently visible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason for this behaviour is that a "Named Range" is actually a named formula rather than a named range: so when you delete the cell(s) that the Named Formula refers to then the part of the Named Formula that refers to the deleted cell gets replaced by #Ref.

Comment: What do you mean by "filter only visible ranges"? Create an array from? Create an Excel filter on the sheet? Create a multi-region Range object that refers only to visible cells? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct behaviour, and it is not related to VSTO.

When you delete a range that had a name, the name is not deleted. Instead, it is replaced with an invalid reference:

```
Sheet1!#REF!
```

The easiest way to detect such names is capturing exception when reading the `RefersToRange` property.